# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException using config.properties file

Tags: data-loader

I am using data loader CLI for upserting users. I have a `config.properties` with following content:

```
sfdc.endpoint=https://pqr.salesforce.com 
sfdc.username=yyy@xxx.com 
sfdc.password=xxxxx
```

When I execute the process from `process-conf.xml`, I get following error:

> ERROR [userUpsert] config.Config decryptProperty (Config.java:704) -
>   Error loading parameter: sfdc.password of type: java.lang.String
>   javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly
>   padded
>
> Unable to run process userUpsert java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.salesforce.dataloader.exception.ControllerInitializationException:
>   Error loading config file:
>   C:\Users\sohan_shirodkar\Desktop\HR_Feed_Automation\config.properties.
>   Please make sure that it exists and is readable

Everything works perfectly fine when I keep properties file empty and hardcode those parameters in xml file. Please note that when I am initializing the parameters in properties file, I am deleting their entries from xml file. I hope this is correct.

I have also verified my encrypted password by decrypting it.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to initialize `process.encryptionKeyFile` value in the properties file itself along with the password. What I feel from this is that both the keys `process.encryptionKeyFile` and `sfdc.password` need to be initialized at the same location i.e. either within the xml file or within the properties file.

I also had to escape all the backslashes(\) in the file path as follows:

> process.encryptionKeyFile=C:\\Users\\sohan_shirodkar\\Desktop\\HR_Feed_Automation\key.txt